# Confusion over plant's "magnetic field" being used to reduce wastage of pesticide

Tags: electromagnetism, biophysics

As far as I am aware, a plant does not have a magnetic field of any significant  magnitude.

What I wonder is, is there any electromagnetic related basis for the crop spraying technique outlined in the science section of a generally highly regarded newspaper and listed below. If the idea was not associated with a university, I would not be asking the question.

[Irish Times Crop Spraying Article](http://www.irishtimes.com/business/maggrow-use-less-grow-more-spray-system-1.2620917) :

> ...is a magnetic spraying technology that helps farmers grow more by using less. The system, which has been three years in development, gives better coverage than conventional crop spraying systems and also reduces spray drift by more than 80 per cent.  [The company} is based at NovaUCD, (University College Dublin) the university’s centre for new ventures.
>
> “The technology is based around attaching magnetic inserts onto a sprayer which sends an electromagnetic charge into the sprayed liquid,”  “All living plants and soil have a magnetic field so the magnetically charged liquid is attracted to its target. The benefits of our technology include increased profitability, increased productivity and better environmental performance.”
> The company has worked closely with UCD to develop its system which has also been independently tested as far afield as Ethiopia, Kenya and the US.

However, this study, [Plant's magnetic field strength is less than a millionth of Earths.](http://news.berkeley.edu/2011/04/07/if-plants-generate-magnetic-fields-they%E2%80%99re-not-sayin%E2%80%99/) seems, to me at least, to make the whole idea a non starter.

> In an article in the Journal of Applied Physics, the UC Berkeley scientists describe.. their ultimate failure to detect a magnetic field. They established, however, that the plant generated no magnetic field greater than a millionth the strength of the magnetic field surrounding us here on Earth.

I appreciate that this may turn out to be a biology based question, but I can't immediately see, from a physics point of view, how this scheme could possibly work.

Comment: At first blush I would ascribe this to the generally poor state of science 'journalism' anymore...

Comment: The exact same s.c.a.m. has been used ten years ago in the US. s.c.a.m. is a technical acronym for this kind of stuff, but I forgot what it stands for... anyway, look at this: http://www.bizjournals.com/jacksonville/stories/2006/03/27/story5.html. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "magnetically charged" by "magically charged" - I would rather agree to that :) (and that's actually how I read it by mistake! ;))

Writing of magnetic charges (=monopoles) actually doesn't increase the plausibility.

I think it's just a hoax (I mean, that the university is involved, not the whole business) - though this word would be not appropriate, if there is something connected to this that is really funded by governmental money.
Actually, it reminds me of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/244880/energy-conservation-in-kinetic-power-plants/244888#244888) (or more directly, [this website](http://rosch-innovations.de/uk_kpp.php)), about a perpetual motion machine. There I strongly suspect, that the "company" might have got governmental subsidies because they produce *green* energy - this is a magic term in Europe. Maybe here there might be also some save-the-environment-money involved???

Comment: Hoax is the wrong word. Try calling the attorney general's office for the legally correct terms.

Comment: @CuriousOne  Ok, so I have my "tut tut, pschaw, humbug..." letter  all ready to go in to the Irish Times, but it's generally a good paper.  I am amazed  at the College though, maybe "associated" just  means  "we have our mail sent there."  Bit surprised  at any real uni involvment.

Comment: Nothing stops you from researching the facts. You can call the college and ask for the details of their involvement. As you can see, a simple internet search shows that the same people have been involved with this in the US ten years ago, which tells you what's really going on. I bet with you that you can probably find magic crop dusting devices being "sold" to unsuspecting (naive) farmers in the early 20th or even late 19th century. :-)

Comment: If you take the trouble to make the research, please let us know, okay? I would be interested, if there is more behind this than a company waiting for naive customers, and a naive journalist writing about it...

Comment: @Ilja  What I intend to do is ring the paper and then  UCD's   accounts department and send on this page by email, stressing the link CuriousOne posted,  and ask them "are they  involved financially  with the company making the claims?". Hopefully, the journalist has  overplayed UCD's involvement.  I will post any reply here.

Comment: thank you :) 

(as I insinuated, there is also the possibility that the journalist is involved... but it would probably be hard to pin him on that...)

Comment: It's not the first time a bona fide Uni gets entangled in something like this. A leading British Uni got caught up in a HHO scam, providing 'research' funds for it.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, @Gert, I googled it, didnt hear. Collecting such things would be worth a good question here, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Ilja: interesting it would be but not really a *question* though...