# Buoyancy perpetual motion machine with compressors at top and decompress-or at bottom

Tags: energy-conservation, fluid-statics, buoyancy, dissipation, perpetual-motion

[a link to consideration about the perpetual motion machine](https://www.rashidahakim.org/2016/12/05/buoyancy-and-perpetual-motion/)
[image: diagram]
[[image]]

diagrams and working out are included above. the assumptions are set to minimise engineering challenge and face perpetual motion machine on a conceptual level. What is wrong about the working?

Comment: "No friction" seems fairly devastating.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Perpetual motion machines don't exist, and even if they did, they don't generate any net energy.  Machines that do generate net energy violate the 1st law of thermodynamics, so they don't exist either.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is just another question in the list of "Yay! I achieved perpetual motion" questions. [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2217/).

Answer (score 1):

In the most general sense possible: if you want to demonstrate perpetual motion (i.e., "free energy") what you must do first to check your work is write down an *energy balance* for the device. You do this by drawing a dashed line around the device on paper, thereby establishing a *control volume* around it, and then do the book-keeping sums for **all** forms of energy that either enter, get stored inside, or exit the control volume.

Any device in which the energy leaving the control volume exceeds that entering it plus what is being stored inside it indicates an error in your analysis. Your homework assignment is then locating that error.