# Why work done to submerge a ball is $pV$?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, fluid-statics, volume

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556/277480) stack post Mr.mark says the work done to submerge a ball is $pV$. I don't seem to comprehend this .

I believe this would be answered in a comment but and answer could help me show my appreciation as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Work done in submerging a weightless sphere, I am getting exactly half the correct, can someone point out my mistake!](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/615924/work-done-in-submerging-a-weightless-sphere-i-am-getting-exactly-half-the-corre)

Comment: No sir I still don't understand

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume that the total amount of water is so large that submerging the sphere raises the overall water height by only a negligible amount. Completely submerging a weightless sphere of volume $V$ is then equivalent to elevating a mass of water $m=\rho V$, where $\rho$ is the water density, by a distance $r$, where $r$ is the sphere radius. The reason is that the completely submerged sphere has its center at a depth of $r$; this is also the center of mass of the water that the sphere displaced. That water is now dispersed at the surface, for a net elevation of $r$.

The energy to elevate a mass is $mgh$ (where $h$ is the height), or $\rho Vgr$ in this case. Let $p$ specifically  represent the pressure at the depth of the center of the just-submerged sphere. By applying the general formula for hydrostatic pressure, we find that $p=\rho g r$ at that depth. Then, the work done in submerging the sphere/elevating the water is $pV$.

Comment: Nice answer. Just to emphasize, the work is only pV if the pressure p is taken at the centroid of the submerged volume.

Comment: Thank you sir ,but I did not understand the first paragraph. Doesn't the elevation of the water depend on the area of the container ? You say the water level raises by r .

Comment: I added an initial sentence for clarification. The overall water height is assumed not to change, which is valid when the total water volume is far greater than the sphere volume.

Comment: "The reason is that the completely submerged sphere has its center at a depth of r; this is also the center of mass of the water that the sphere displaced. That water is now dispersed at the surface, for a net elevation of r." Sir this part of the answer only confuses me I've understood the rest.How can the center of mass of the displaced water be at r if it's negligible and I'm also confused by "net elevation of r"

Comment: Where the sphere is submerged, we originally had a spherical volume of water at depth $r$ (on average). That water is now displaced by the sphere and is floating on the surrounding water at zero depth. Therefore, the water was raised by a height $r$. Hope this clarifies. If not, please try drawing a diagram of the problem before and after the sphere is submerged, including where the water is originally and where it ends up.