# Could a perpetual motion machine be made using a filling buoyant object that sinks when filled and releases when bottoming out?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, buoyancy, dissipation, perpetual-motion

Could you make a perpetual motion machine via buoyancy? If you started with 2 types of fluids with different buoyancy. Then add a buoyant object capable of filling with the top fluid where it closes upon filling and then sinks from the additional weight. Then  when it sinks it bottoms out and mechanically vents some of the top more buoyant fluid, thus floating back to the top and refilling again. Would that work? I’m not a scientist obviously.

Comment: The answer to "Can you make a perpetual motion machine by X" is no.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/556/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

> when it sinks it bottoms out and mechanically vents some of the top more buoyant fluid

This part will always require more energy than was produced by the initial stage.

So, no.